# UISegmentedControl from AppDelegate

Tags: ios4, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl that I need to access the selected segment in the app delegate.  I have tried to wire an IBAction of value changed to the app delegate but it crashes.  All I need is the current selected state when it is changed.

Comment: Where is the segmented control located?  What error do you get?  Why does the app delegate need the segmented control's value?

Comment: The segmented control I in the view controller. The app delegate needs the value only once the app exits

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer the following link 
http://derekneely.com/2009/11/iphone-development-global-variables/ 
keep a common object and store your value in that so that you can get it in delegate function.